# How to create a wallet using the docker image?

Tags: docker

In [this documentation](https://tezos.gitlab.io/introduction/howtouse.html#a-simple-wallet) it says:

> The client is also a basic wallet and after the activation above you will notice that the directory .tezos-client has been populated with 3 files public_key_hashs, public_keys and secret_keys.

But when running in docker, it presumably uses some other directory inside the docker container which is not obviously accessible.

How can I access my keys, or create a wallet using the docker image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `tezos-client show address <name> -S` will show you the public and secret key of the user `name`. For instance, assuming that the dockerized tezos-client is accessible through the `./babylonnet.sh`, you can run:

```
./babylonnet.sh client show address <name> -S
```

However, you can also find the directory that corresponds to `~/.tezos-client` used by docker. The dockerized version uses two docker volumes to store data:

```
$ sudo docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               babylonnet_client_data
local               babylonnet_node_data
```

We inspect the first one:

```
$ sudo docker volume inspect babylonnet_client_data
[
    {
        ...,
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/babylonnet_client_data/_data",
        ...
    }
]
```

We can access the mountpoint directly (Note: this required super-user privilegies in my setup) to find the desired keys:

```
$ sudo ls /var/lib/docker/volumes/babylonnet_client_data/_data/ 
config  public_key_hashs  public_keys  secret_keys
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make this work using the following commands:

```
./babylonnet.sh client gen keys MY_WALLET_NAME
./babylonnet.sh client show address MY_WALLET_NAME -S
```